# How to export desired number of documents from a mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I know we can take mongo dump of a collection . I would like to know whether it is possible to take dump of only required number of documents from a mongo collection. My catalog collection have hundreds of thousands of documents , however I need only recent 2000 documents as a dump for sync purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can limit the number of documents from a collection using `--query` option.Inside the query, you could `sort` the documents by `created_date`(*since you want recent documents only, you must have a similar field in your document, do not try to sort by _id because in some case,ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order*) and `limit` documents to 2000 using the query.

But, `mongodump --query` doesn't directly support the `sort and limit` operation. So, you need to do some workarounds in your query.

Firstly, you could fetch the `2000th record`, by `sorting` on the basis of your `created_date` in `ascending` order as:

```
db.collection.find().sort({created_date:1}).skip(1999).limit(1)
```

This will give you the `2000th record`. Inside that record, you will also have the `value of created_date`. Now using that `value`, you could run mongodump as:

```
mongodump --db <db-name> --collection <collection-name> --query '{"created_date":{$lte:{$date:<value-in-milliseconds>}}}'
```

*Note that, you need to specify date in milliseconds here, because `--query doesn't support ISO dates directly`.*

For more information, see [--query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query)

**UPDATE**

However, you could use `ISO dates` in the query by specifying query in a separate file, for eg: `query.json` as:

```
{"created_date": {"$lte": < ISODate("...")-value-of-your-created_date >}}
```

Then you could do mongodump as:

```
mongodump --db <db-name> --collection <collection-name> --queryFile query.json
```

For more information, see [--queryFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--queryFile)

Comment: `mongoexport` now supports `--skip()`, `--limit()`, `--sort()`, which makes this a lot easier.